# POST form parameter being encoded by Javascript function on Login page, Is it possible to pass into cURL/Bash?

Tags: javascript, bash, curl

I'm trying to automate logging into a site via cURL and it was giving me some grief. It has 4 parameters in the form POST data: encoded, goto, nonce, and URL. My issue is with the 'encoded' parameter, which is basically a hash of the username,password, and cookie. Dug around on the login page and found this Javascript function:

```
  function encode() {
    document.submitForm.encoded.value = document.logonForm.username.value + ":" + md5(document.logonForm.username.value + ":" + document.logonForm.password.value + ":" + "161d1eac01829r1d");  // sets the hidden field value to whatever md5 returns.
  }
```

Where the '161d1eac01829r1d' value is the cookie/nonce parameter. This 'encode' function is called once the user hits the 'Login' button on the page. The MD5 function that the 'encode' function refers to is also in the page's code, and from what I can tell it sort of makes it's own hash. It's basically the md5.js code that you can find anywhere online, but the thing that is leaving me scratching my head is that the hash is different each time I do a login through the GUI, which makes a bit of sense since the cookie is different each time, but for the most part it should remain the same, so I'm not exactly sure how the function below is scrambling the parameters passed to it.

```
if (window.focus) self.focus();

function openAnyWindow(url, name) {
  var l = openAnyWindow.arguments.length;
  var w = "";
  var h = "";
  var features = "";
  for (i=2; i<l; i++) {
    var param = openAnyWindow.arguments[i];
    if ( (parseInt(param) == 0) || (isNaN(parseInt(param))) ) {
      features += param + ',';
    } else {
      (w == "") ? w = "width=" + param + "," : h = "height=" + param;
    }
  }
  features += w + h;
  var code = "popupWin = window.open(url, name";
  if (l > 2) code += ", '" + features;
  code += "')";
  eval(code);
}

// Derived from the RSA Data Security, Inc. MD5 Message Digest Algorithm
//
// Copyright (c) 1998 Art & Logic, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
// Copyright (c) 1998 Rapid Logic, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
// Copyright (c) 1996 Henri Torgemane. All Rights Reserved.
//

function array(n)
{
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) this[i]=0;
        this.length=n;
}

// Some basic logical functions had to be rewritten because of a bug in
// Javascript.. Just try to compute 0xffffffff >> 4 with it..
// Of course, these functions are slower than the original would be, but
// at least, they work!
//
function integer(n) { return n%(0xffffffff+1); }

function shr(a,b)
{
        a=integer(a);
        b=integer(b);

        if (a-0x80000000>=0)
        {
                a   = a%0x80000000;
                a >>= b;
                a  += 0x40000000 >> (b-1);
        }
        else a >>= b;

        return a;
}

function shl1(a)
{
        a = a%0x80000000;

        if (a&0x40000000==0x40000000)
        {
                a-=0x40000000;
                a*=2;
                a+=0x80000000;
        }
        else a*=2;

        return a;
}

function shl(a,b)
{
        a = integer(a);
        b = integer(b);

        for (var i=0; i<b; i++)
                a=shl1(a);

        return a;
}

function and(a,b)
{
        a = integer(a);
        b = integer(b);

        var t1 = (a-0x80000000);
        var t2 = (b-0x80000000);

        if (t1>=0)
                if (t2>=0)
                        return ((t1&t2)+0x80000000);
                else
                        return (t1&b);
        else
                if (t2>=0)
                        return (a&t2);
                else
                        return (a&b);
}

function or(a,b)
{
    a = integer(a);
    b = integer(b);

        var t1 = (a-0x80000000);
        var t2 = (b-0x80000000);

        if (t1>=0)
                if (t2>=0)
                        return ((t1|t2)+0x80000000);
                else
                        return ((t1|b)+0x80000000);
        else
                if (t2>=0)
                        return ((a|t2)+0x80000000);
                else
                        return (a|b);
}

function xor(a,b)
{
        a = integer(a);
        b = integer(b);

        var t1 = (a-0x80000000);
        var t2 = (b-0x80000000);

        if (t1>=0)
                if (t2>=0)
                        return (t1^t2);
                else
                        return ((t1^b)+0x80000000);
        else
                if (t2>=0)
                        return ((a^t2)+0x80000000);
                else
                        return (a^b);
}

function not(a)
{
        a = integer(a);

        return (0xffffffff-a);
}

/* Here begin the real algorithm */

        var state = new array(4);
        var count = new array(2);
                count[0] = 0;
                count[1] = 0;
        var buffer = new array(64);
        var transformBuffer = new array(16);
        var digestBits = new array(16);

        var S11 = 7;
        var S12 = 12;
        var S13 = 17;
        var S14 = 22;
        var S21 = 5;
        var S22 = 9;
        var S23 = 14;
        var S24 = 20;
        var S31 = 4;
        var S32 = 11;
        var S33 = 16;
        var S34 = 23;
        var S41 = 6;
        var S42 = 10;
        var S43 = 15;
        var S44 = 21;

    function F(x,y,z)
        {
        return or(and(x,y),and(not(x),z));
    }

    function G(x,y,z)
        {
        return or(and(x,z),and(y,not(z)));
    }

    function H(x,y,z)
        {
        return xor(xor(x,y),z);
    }

    function I(x,y,z)
        {
        return xor(y,or(x,not(z)));
    }

    function rotateLeft(a,n)
        {
        return or(shl(a,n),(shr(a,(32-n))));
    }

     function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac)
        {
        a = a+F(b, c, d) + x + ac;
        a = rotateLeft(a, s);
        a = a+b;
        return a;
    }

    function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac)
        {
        a = a+G(b,c,d)+x+ac;
        a = rotateLeft(a,s);
        a = a+b;
        return a;
    }

    function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac)
        {
        a = a+H(b, c, d) + x + ac;
        a = rotateLeft(a, s);
        a = a+b;
        return a;
    }

    function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac)
        {
        a = a+I(b, c, d) + x + ac;
        a = rotateLeft(a, s);
        a = a+b;
        return a;
    }

    function transform(buf,offset)
        {
        var a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0;
        var x = transformBuffer;

        a = state[0];
        b = state[1];
        c = state[2];
        d = state[3];

        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                {
            x[i] = and(buf[i*4+offset],0xff);

            for (j = 1; j < 4; j++)
                        {
                x[i]+=shl(and(buf[i*4+j+offset] ,0xff), j * 8);
            }
        }

        /* Round 1 */
        a = FF ( a, b, c, d, x[ 0], S11, 0xd76aa478); /* 1 */
        d = FF ( d, a, b, c, x[ 1], S12, 0xe8c7b756); /* 2 */
        c = FF ( c, d, a, b, x[ 2], S13, 0x242070db); /* 3 */
        b = FF ( b, c, d, a, x[ 3], S14, 0xc1bdceee); /* 4 */
        a = FF ( a, b, c, d, x[ 4], S11, 0xf57c0faf); /* 5 */
        d = FF ( d, a, b, c, x[ 5], S12, 0x4787c62a); /* 6 */
        c = FF ( c, d, a, b, x[ 6], S13, 0xa8304613); /* 7 */
        b = FF ( b, c, d, a, x[ 7], S14, 0xfd469501); /* 8 */
        a = FF ( a, b, c, d, x[ 8], S11, 0x698098d8); /* 9 */
        d = FF ( d, a, b, c, x[ 9], S12, 0x8b44f7af); /* 10 */
        c = FF ( c, d, a, b, x[10], S13, 0xffff5bb1); /* 11 */
        b = FF ( b, c, d, a, x[11], S14, 0x895cd7be); /* 12 */
        a = FF ( a, b, c, d, x[12], S11, 0x6b901122); /* 13 */
        d = FF ( d, a, b, c, x[13], S12, 0xfd987193); /* 14 */
        c = FF ( c, d, a, b, x[14], S13, 0xa679438e); /* 15 */
        b = FF ( b, c, d, a, x[15], S14, 0x49b40821); /* 16 */

        /* Round 2 */
        a = GG ( a, b, c, d, x[ 1], S21, 0xf61e2562); /* 17 */
        d = GG ( d, a, b, c, x[ 6], S22, 0xc040b340); /* 18 */
        c = GG ( c, d, a, b, x[11], S23, 0x265e5a51); /* 19 */
        b = GG ( b, c, d, a, x[ 0], S24, 0xe9b6c7aa); /* 20 */
        a = GG ( a, b, c, d, x[ 5], S21, 0xd62f105d); /* 21 */
        d = GG ( d, a, b, c, x[10], S22,  0x2441453); /* 22 */
        c = GG ( c, d, a, b, x[15], S23, 0xd8a1e681); /* 23 */
        b = GG ( b, c, d, a, x[ 4], S24, 0xe7d3fbc8); /* 24 */
        a = GG ( a, b, c, d, x[ 9], S21, 0x21e1cde6); /* 25 */
        d = GG ( d, a, b, c, x[14], S22, 0xc33707d6); /* 26 */
        c = GG ( c, d, a, b, x[ 3], S23, 0xf4d50d87); /* 27 */
        b = GG ( b, c, d, a, x[ 8], S24, 0x455a14ed); /* 28 */
        a = GG ( a, b, c, d, x[13], S21, 0xa9e3e905); /* 29 */
        d = GG ( d, a, b, c, x[ 2], S22, 0xfcefa3f8); /* 30 */
        c = GG ( c, d, a, b, x[ 7], S23, 0x676f02d9); /* 31 */
        b = GG ( b, c, d, a, x[12], S24, 0x8d2a4c8a); /* 32 */

        /* Round 3 */
        a = HH ( a, b, c, d, x[ 5], S31, 0xfffa3942); /* 33 */
        d = HH ( d, a, b, c, x[ 8], S32, 0x8771f681); /* 34 */
        c = HH ( c, d, a, b, x[11], S33, 0x6d9d6122); /* 35 */
        b = HH ( b, c, d, a, x[14], S34, 0xfde5380c); /* 36 */
        a = HH ( a, b, c, d, x[ 1], S31, 0xa4beea44); /* 37 */
        d = HH ( d, a, b, c, x[ 4], S32, 0x4bdecfa9); /* 38 */
        c = HH ( c, d, a, b, x[ 7], S33, 0xf6bb4b60); /* 39 */
        b = HH ( b, c, d, a, x[10], S34, 0xbebfbc70); /* 40 */
        a = HH ( a, b, c, d, x[13], S31, 0x289b7ec6); /* 41 */
        d = HH ( d, a, b, c, x[ 0], S32, 0xeaa127fa); /* 42 */
        c = HH ( c, d, a, b, x[ 3], S33, 0xd4ef3085); /* 43 */
        b = HH ( b, c, d, a, x[ 6], S34,  0x4881d05); /* 44 */
        a = HH ( a, b, c, d, x[ 9], S31, 0xd9d4d039); /* 45 */
        d = HH ( d, a, b, c, x[12], S32, 0xe6db99e5); /* 46 */
        c = HH ( c, d, a, b, x[15], S33, 0x1fa27cf8); /* 47 */
        b = HH ( b, c, d, a, x[ 2], S34, 0xc4ac5665); /* 48 */

        /* Round 4 */
        a = II ( a, b, c, d, x[ 0], S41, 0xf4292244); /* 49 */
        d = II ( d, a, b, c, x[ 7], S42, 0x432aff97); /* 50 */
        c = II ( c, d, a, b, x[14], S43, 0xab9423a7); /* 51 */
        b = II ( b, c, d, a, x[ 5], S44, 0xfc93a039); /* 52 */
        a = II ( a, b, c, d, x[12], S41, 0x655b59c3); /* 53 */
        d = II ( d, a, b, c, x[ 3], S42, 0x8f0ccc92); /* 54 */
        c = II ( c, d, a, b, x[10], S43, 0xffeff47d); /* 55 */
        b = II ( b, c, d, a, x[ 1], S44, 0x85845dd1); /* 56 */
        a = II ( a, b, c, d, x[ 8], S41, 0x6fa87e4f); /* 57 */
        d = II ( d, a, b, c, x[15], S42, 0xfe2ce6e0); /* 58 */
        c = II ( c, d, a, b, x[ 6], S43, 0xa3014314); /* 59 */
        b = II ( b, c, d, a, x[13], S44, 0x4e0811a1); /* 60 */
        a = II ( a, b, c, d, x[ 4], S41, 0xf7537e82); /* 61 */
        d = II ( d, a, b, c, x[11], S42, 0xbd3af235); /* 62 */
        c = II ( c, d, a, b, x[ 2], S43, 0x2ad7d2bb); /* 63 */
        b = II ( b, c, d, a, x[ 9], S44, 0xeb86d391); /* 64 */

        state[0] +=a;
        state[1] +=b;
        state[2] +=c;
        state[3] +=d;

    }

    function init()
        {
        count[0]=count[1] = 0;
        state[0] = 0x67452301;
        state[1] = 0xefcdab89;
        state[2] = 0x98badcfe;
        state[3] = 0x10325476;
        for (i = 0; i < digestBits.length; i++)
            digestBits[i] = 0;
    }

    function update(b)
        {
        var index,i;

        index = and(shr(count[0],3) , 0x3f);
        if (count[0]<0xffffffff-7)
          count[0] += 8;
        else {
          count[1]++;
          count[0]-=0xffffffff+1;
          count[0]+=8;
        }
        buffer[index] = and(b,0xff);
        if (index  >= 63) {
            transform(buffer, 0);
        }
    }

    function finish()
        {
        var bits = new array(8);
        var padding;
        var i=0, index=0, padLen=0;

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
            bits[i] = and(shr(count[0],(i * 8)), 0xff);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
            bits[i+4]=and(shr(count[1],(i * 8)), 0xff);
        }

        index = and(shr(count[0], 3) ,0x3f);
        padLen = (index < 56) ? (56 - index) : (120 - index);
        padding = new array(64);
        padding[0] = 0x80;

        for (i=0;i<padLen;i++)
          update(padding[i]);

        for (i=0;i<8;i++)
          update(bits[i]);

        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                        {
                digestBits[i*4+j] = and(shr(state[i], (j * 8)) , 0xff);
            }
        }
    }

/* End of the MD5 algorithm */

function hexa(n) {
 var hexa_h = "0123456789abcdef";
 var hexa_c="";
 var hexa_m=n;
 for (hexa_i=0;hexa_i<8;hexa_i++) {
   hexa_c=hexa_h.charAt(Math.abs(hexa_m)%16)+hexa_c;
   hexa_m=Math.floor(hexa_m/16);
 }
 return hexa_c;
}


var ascii="01234567890123456789012345678901" +
          " !\"#" + '\$' + "%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"+
          "[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";

function md5(entree)
{
 var l,s,k,ka,kb,kc,kd;

 init();
 for (k=0;k<entree.length;k++) {
   l=entree.charAt(k);
   update(ascii.lastIndexOf(l));
 }

 finish();
 ka=kb=kc=kd=0;
 for (i=0;i<4;i++) ka+=shl(digestBits[15-i], (i*8));
 for (i=4;i<8;i++) kb+=shl(digestBits[15-i], ((i-4)*8));
 for (i=8;i<12;i++) kc+=shl(digestBits[15-i], ((i-8)*8));
 for (i=12;i<16;i++) kd+=shl(digestBits[15-i], ((i-12)*8));
 s=hexa(kd)+hexa(kc)+hexa(kb)+hexa(ka);
 return s;
}

  function encode() {
    document.submitForm.encoded.value = document.logonForm.username.value + ":" + md5(document.logonForm.username.value + ":" + document.logonForm.password.value + ":" + "161d1eac01829r1d");  // sets the hidden field value to whatever md5 returns.
  }
```

I tried to make my own MD5 hash in the bash script and passing it into the --data field by doing:

```
read -sp 'Password:' passvar
cookie=`cut -f7 -d '    ' cookies1.txt | tail -n 1`
md5=`echo "someuser:$passvar:$cookie" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d ' '`
varmd5=`echo "someuser:$md5"` 

# The last cut command in the md5 variable is to get rid of the trailing '-'

`curl -c cookies1.txt -b cookies1.txt -v -X POST --data 'encoded='"$varmd5"'&nonce='"$cookie"'&goto=Login&URL=/' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0' -H 'Host: some_ip' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://some_ip/Home.html' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -L http://some_ip/Home.html > test_output.html`
```

No luck on that. But, upon opening the 'test_output.html' page, it said "invalid password' which is more than what I got before which was just the login page itself, so I'm assuming the correct parameters are being passed, but it just doesn't like the 'encoded' parameter I passed into it. I also tried to just pass the username and password into the --data field too but no luck on that either.

I'm ultimately hoping to write a bash script to log into the site and download a few pages, but I need to get this login thing figured out first.

My knowledge of Javascript is basically non-existent so I'm hoping someone can look at that MD5 function and tell me if theres a way to pass the username and password parameters I provide into it to get the correct 'encoded' parameter or let me know if these JS functions were likely built to prevent that sort of thing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: probably easier to do this using a headless browser

Comment: Is it possible to pass login creds into firefox --headless? that screenshot function might be the way to go but a quick Google search didn't give me anything useful about passing login creds through the headless mode and unfortunately the environment I'm in won't allow me to download Selenium or anything similar to make this easy.

Comment: My comment implied using something like selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp.....I got it.....Just needed that '-n' option in echo to get rid of that trailing new line character and make it the correct md5 that the js script was producing.

```
md5=`echo -n "someuser:$passvar:$cookie" | md5sum | cut -f1 -d '-'`
```